# Traduzir medalhas para o português

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

A página sobre as medalhas ainda está em inglês. Precisamos traduzi-las.

[image: Badges2Medalhas]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217827/missing-images-on-badge3-class-on-badges-on-stackoverflow-in-portugess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As medalhas vão ser traduzidas... Mas só daqui a algum tempo.

Comment: Nomenclatura e descrição ou só descrição?