# Tradução para a medalha "Tumbleweed"

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

A medalha "Tumbleweed" ainda não tem um nome traduzido (é uma palavra difícil de traduzir). Então estou abrindo este tópico para levantar sugestões para traduzí-la.

Há um chapéu para ela chamado "Lonesome cowboy".

Observação: Isto não é uma duplicata de [Traduzir medalhas para o português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7/traduzir-medalhas-para-o-portugues)

Comment: Nada vai ficar legal :)

Comment: Fui besta nessa. Vou retirar o que eu disse, tem umas ideias bem legais :)

Comment: Fui com a mais votada. O único "problema" é que o nome do filme em Portugal não é "Esqueceram de Mim"... Mas a expressão é óbvia o suficiente pra fazer sentido pros Portugueses (eu acho).

Comment: @Gabe Talvez eu deva eu aceitar a minha própria resposta para encerrar logo essa discussão e então você bater o martelo que o nome vai ser "Esqueceram de mim". O que você acha?

Comment: @Victor Certamente. Vai pro ar no próximo build.

Comment: @Gabe Excelente. Aceitei a minha própria resposta.

Comment: Já está em produção. :) Obrigado @Gabe

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Viajando um pouco na maionese para exercitar algumas possíveis traduções:

- <strike>Sozinho</strike>
- <strike>Solitário</strike>
- <strike>Ninguém em casa</strike>
- <strike>Abandonado</strike>
- Esqueceram de mim
- <strike>Arbusto seco ao vento</strike>

Comment: Gostaria que o SOPT tivesse personalidade como o SO original. As badges são bem-humoradas, leves e inteligentes. Não vejo porque não usarmos coisas da nossa cultura.
Obviamente que pode ser também cultura pop, quando "esqueceram de mim" parece uma ótima alternativa.

Comment: A que mais gostei é Esqueceram de Mim!

Comment: Se tivesse separado, seria melhor p/ votar (como a gente perde tempo com uma coisa tão boba :) )

Comment: Esqueceram de mim é "a boa" dessa lista.

Comment: @bigown Pois é, devia ter colocado em várias respostas. De qualquer forma, acho que a sugestão "Esqueceram de mim" claramente supera as outras desta resposta.

Comment: Forever Alone também pode fazer alusão ao mesmo sentido (apesar de ser outro termo em inglês)

Comment: Esqueceram de mim ficou bom, mas senti falta de `marasmo` entre as opções =)

Answer (score 10):

Crii-crii-crii (som de grilo cantando)

Não sei se é auto-idenfificável...

Comment: Se alguém vier a receber esta medalha e for no link da pergunta correspondente, acho que dá para sacar o que aconteceu.

Comment: Olha, pensando bem, acho essa a melhor alternativa. Como o @mgibsonbr já mencionou, é a piada sonora para solidão mais usada na nossa cultura. Deve funcionar bem como o Victor também sugeriu, com a explicação da medalha. Eu só usaria `cri-cri-cri` ao invés de dois i's por palavra.

Comment: @LuizVieira, a intenção dos dois i's é fazer o prolongamento do som, como faz o grilo. Consideras que isso é secundário? Ou tens alguma outra sugestão nesse sentido?

Comment: @LuizAngioletti Como é uma onomatopeia, creio que podemos escrever como preferirmos. Eu só acho estranho escrever em português com dois "i" seguidos, por isso a minha preferência é por "cri-cri-cri". :) (Mas, claro, aceito o que a maioria preferir, se essa opção for escolhida)

Comment: P.S.: Por curiosidade (admito que sou realmente muito curioso! hehe), fui procurar como se chama o barulho do grilo. Achei [essa referência](http://www.ciberduvidas.com/pergunta.php?id=13158): o grilo canta, estridula, estrila, grilha, guizalha, trila ou tritina.

Comment: @LuizVieira, cri-cri-cri é muito próximo de 'cri-cri', uma expressão que significa 'chato' em algumas regiões do Brasil.

Comment: @LuizAngioletti Eu entendo, mas isso é discutível. Um "cri" a mais faz bastante diferença. E, além disso, o entendimento está parcialmente ligado ao fato do usuário ler posteriormente a explicação da medalha (assim como *tumbleweed*), né? :) Bom, talvez melhor ainda seja "cri, cri, cri" (a vírgula talvez passe a ideia de ações consecutivas e desfaça essa possível confusão).

Comment: Cri, Cri, Cri...

Answer (score 8):

Estou enrolando há algum tempo a postagem da minha revisão da lista de medalhas. Para tumbleweed, minhas sugestões são (em ordem de preferência):

### A ver navios

Ou

### Calmaria

Ou

### Sepulcral

(por causa da expressão "silêncio sepulcral")

Mais uma:

### Falando com as paredes

(Meio longa, né?)

Comment: Juram que não gostaram de "a ver navios"? Achei que pelo menos os portugueses fossem gostar, :P

Comment: Particularmente gostei de "A ver navios".

Comment: Obrigado @Victor, que bom que não sou só eu `:)`

Comment: Falando com as paredes é a melhor

Comment: Eu gosto de sepulcral. :)

Comment: Gostei de "A ver navios". Ainda prefiro "Esqueceram de Mim", mas em Portugal o nome do filme não é esse...

Answer (score 8):

Antes de ler a resposta do @Zuul não fazia ideia do que era "Tumbleweed", mas agora consigo visualizar perfeitamente: não é um *staple* da comédia [americana], alguém perguntar/dizer alguma coisa e - ao ficar no maior silêncio - passar uma "bola de plantas secas" rolando pela tela? (não importa em que ambiente isso ocorre)

E o que temos de mais parecido com isso por aqui?

## Grilo cantando

Comment: na mesma linha, que tal "crii-crii-crii"

Comment: @LuizAngioletti talvez voce devesse criar uma resposta, já viu quantos votos tem seu comentario?

Comment: @Math, feito. Obrigado pelo toque.

Answer (score 6):

#### Significado da Palavra

A palavra Tumbleweed tem dois significados relacionados, ambos em baixo traduzidos para Português:

Tumbleweed

- [como parte da planta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumbleweed)

  > A parte acima do solo de um certo número de plantas que, uma vez maduras e secas, soltam-se da raiz e saem a voar com o vento.
- [como expressão urbana](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tumbleweed)

  > Um conjunto de pedaços de plantas secas, que vemos a rebolar pelo chão do deserto devido ao vento.

#### O objectivo da medalha

Esta medalha é de certa forma um [prémio de consolação](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1576/184576) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>, ninguém viu a pergunta ou ninguém respondeu à mesma durante uma semana inteira, então, o sistema atribui este consolo ao utilizador para que ele se auto-motive a aguardar um pouco mais.

#### Tradução sugerida

Atendendo a tudo isto, na minha opinião, a tradução terá que transmitir este mesmo sentimento de abandono e vivência ao sabor do vento, pelo que sugiro:

## Ignorado

Comment: Só por curiosidade: parece que o nome válido para tradução literal é "estepicursor". Coloquei umas referências na minha própria resposta. :)

Comment: Outra curiosidade: o Zuul é a única pessoa que recebeu essa medalha no Meta SO-PT...

Answer (score 5):

secando ao sol

parece uma boa alternativa. Não sei porque. =P

Comment: Muito bom, mantém o espírito de brincadeira, que afinal é um dos pilares da aprendizagem :)

Answer (score 4):

Ninguém mencionou, então apenas para constar:

**Bola de feno**

Procurei `tumbleweed` no Goole e a primeira coisa que ele me mostrou foi essa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Claro que não precisamos fazer uma tradução literal da medalha, mas resolvi indicar esse nome apenas para termos mais opções. Várias sugestões dadas aqui são sensacionais! Sinceramente não sei qual escolher.

Comment: Não temos bola de feno no Brasil, mas por incrível que pareça acho que todo mundo sabe o que é.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que seria interessante fazer uma nova pergunta para escolher esta tradução. Poderia dar um prazo de 30 dias para cada um adicionar uma ideia por resposta, após esse prazo aquele que tivesse mais votos seria escolhido.

**Sugestões:**

- Vácuo
- Fantasma
- Despercebido

Comment: Não há necessidade de fazer outra pergunta, mas gosto das suas sugestões de nome.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal **bombando**?

Assim como *tumbleweed*, tem um caráter cômico ligado à incongruência da situação e também motiva "levemente" o OP a tentar melhorar a pergunta. :)

O único problema é que provavelmente não tem o mesmo [significado](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/bombando/) para os colegas portugueses...

**EDIT:**

Eu ia colocar isso como um comentário na resposta do @Zuul, mas não coube. :)
Apenas por curiosidade: a tradução literal parece ser "**Estepicursor**". O artigo da Wikipedia para *Tumbleweed* usa esse nome [na versão em espanhol](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estepicursor), e embora não exista o artigo em português eu achei duas fontes que indicam que o nome é válido também em português:

[Fonte 1](https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.418255121561081.102274.245748968811698&type=1):

> "Tumbleweed" ou "ESTEPicursor" é um tipo de planta que vive em zonas
>   de ESTEPE, que é uma transição vegetativa e climática entre a savana e
>   o deserto.  Em português, não existe uma tradução para o nome comum, e
>   é conhecida pelo seu gênero como "Salsola".

[Fonte 2](http://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130314143400AAz4UHA):

> Em botânica, são chamados de estepicursores espécies de plantas que
>   vivem em áreas de estepe ou terreno baldio, uma vez fructificadas,
>   inicia com o vento o transporte de um lugar para outro, atirando-os ou
>   arrastando-os, assim as suas sementes irão afrouxar e dispersar.

De todas as formas, não acho esse seja um bom nome pra medalha. hehehe

Comment: Para o "chapéu" eu sugeriria "[Pequeno Príncipe](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Petit_Prince)". Se tiver que explicar a piada, então não serve. hehe :)

Comment: A medalha poderia chamar "Salsola", hahaha!

Comment: É uma boa! Até "soa" engraçado. hahaha

Comment: não entendi pq `bombando`, não seria o contrário? des-bombando? rsrs..

Comment: @Math A ideia é ser irônico com a situação. De fato, a pergunta estaria bem no oposto de "bombando" quando a medalha fosse concedida. :)

Comment: hummm... tindí, mas não gostei, +0 pra você :)

Comment: acho q eu to meio lento hoje, não entendi o bombando, nao entendi salsola, não entedi pqno principe =/ acho q volto aqui mais tarde pra ver

Comment: @Math Hahaha Acho que minhas <strike>tantativas de piadas</strike> ideias acabaram de migrar para a categoria "não serve". :)

Comment: rsrs... relaxa, o que vale é o [Brainstorming](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainstorming)

Comment: Posso explicar as piadas? :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Manda ver! :)

Comment: @Math "Salsola" está na definição de "Estepicursor" acima, e é uma palavra com sonoridade engraçada. O pequeno príncipe vivia sozinho lá no planeta dele -- se entendi bem a piada...

Comment: Isso ai. Bom, ao menos ele tinha uma rosa falante. hehe :)