# Quem é Strunk & White em português?

Tags: debate, tradução, tags, medalhas

Bom, no mesmo espírito [desta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/traducao-para-a-medalha-tumbleweed) sobre qual a tradução mais adequada da medalha Tumbleweed, a medalha Strunk & White ainda não tem tradução para o português. Segundo a [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style), a graça está no livro *Elements of Style*, que "ensina a escrever corretamente (em inglês)". A minha sugestão óbvia de tradução é (Professor) [Pasquale](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasquale_Cipro_Neto). Quais as outras ideias de tradução?

Comment: É legal, só não sei se os não brasileiros sabem quem é o professor Pasquale. Apesar que "Esqueceram de Mim", também não. Em Portugal o filme chama-se "Sozinho em Casa". Mas pelo menos dá entendimento mesmo não sabendo do trocadilho com o filme. E não sei se teria algum problema em usar o nome dele oficialmente.

Comment: Não sabia quem era o (Professor) Pasquale não, mas agora que cliquei no link, pronto... :D

Comment: É verdade, @Zuul. Se já é difícil existir algum linguista ou gramático nacionalmente conhecido no Brasil, imagine internacionalmente.

Comment: Isto nunca mais foi traduzido?

Comment: Se fossem nomes de variáveis, eu chamaria de _Editor Bronze_, _Editor Prata_ e _Editor Ouro_ e não pensaria mais nisso. :P Ou chamaria de "Pasquale & <gramático Português de Portugal>", mesmo que nunca tenham escrito algo juntos.

Comment: Eu não vejo o porque de "imitar" o sentido do SOen sobre está medalha, realmente precisa ser o nome de alguém, ou algo ligado a língua, o sentido da medalha é "edição" e não necessariamente "correção de textos". Acho a primeira ideia do @Piovezan mais interessante.

Comment: Eu ia deixar a mesma sugestão aqui, e aí notei que seria uma dupliada. Pra mim "Professor Pasquale" é a tradução natural dessa medalha - e as sugestões nas respostas estão fora. A  idéia é correão de textos mesmo, não "alguém ligado a lingua".

Answer (score 8):

Contra-sugestão: e se trocássemos a medalha de prata para "Revisor", e deixássemos o Pasquale para a de ouro?

Comment: Será que o Pasquale é conhecido em Portugal?

Comment: Provavelmente não.

Comment: Eu daria upvote se o Pasquale fosse conhecido fora do Brasil. É o único problema.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez O problema é que não sei se existe alguém que atenda a esse requisito. Ser conhecido no Brasil já é difícil! O professor Raimundo e o professor Girafales são mais conhecidos aqui que o Pasquale.

Comment: É-me estranha essa ordem. Um editor é, via de regra, mais experiente e com mais responsabilidades do que um revisor.

Comment: Eu prefiro o Girafales ao Pasquale /s

Comment: Não é conhecido, nem faço ideia de quem seja (já vi o link do wiki do homem)

Comment: Mais valia por Camões :)

Comment: Camões sim! Aí acho que resolve bem!

Comment: @Bacco de volta ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. tou só passando pelos arredores. Fico mais nos bastidores, me divertindo com o pessoal do "mimimi" :)

Answer (score 5):

Minha sugestão seria escritores famosos de ambos países: (Machado de) Assis, Eça (de Queiroz), (Luís de) Camões.

Comment: Esses caras mereciam ouro, né? Menos o Eça de Queiroz, acho ele um chato :)

Comment: Eu concordaria se eles tivessem sido editores de alguma publicação, por exemplo. Eles foram escritores, certo?

Comment: Grandes escritores são bons editores também. (:

Comment: A ideia é interessante, mas a ordem é complicada. Camões é reconhecidamente o maior poeta da língua portuguesa, mas como ficam os outros escritores?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, você diz que o Bechara é imortal, mas o Machado *fundou* a ABL ;)

Comment: Acho que Camões pare ser a mais adequada.

Answer (score 5):

## Corretor de textos

É algo simples que se encaixa bem com o significado da medalha.

Comment: Talvez apenas "Corretor"?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal - Acho que não, pois isso poderia dar a entender ser "Corretor de seguros" ou "Corretor de imóveis".

Comment: `Corretor automático` ia ser boa!

Comment: @falsarella Gostei. Como não quero roubar a sua sugestão, proponho que poste como resposta. Vou votar a favor.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Nesse caso, quem achar legal, segue o link para minha resposta: [Corretor automático](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4061/22360).

Answer (score 4):

## Passando a limpo

Uma vez que esta medalha é premiada por ter feito 80 edições, nada mais justo do que dar a ela este nome.

Ou, se você preferir conjugar o verbo no particípio ao invés do gerúndio, então pode ser:

## Passado a limpo

Comment: Uma boa sugestão, +1

Comment: "Passado a limpo" não seria melhor?

Comment: @JorgeB. Não sei, talvez. Consigo pensar a favor tanto pelo lado do gerúndio quanto pelo lado do particípio. Entretanto não tenho nenhum argumento real para preferir um em detrimento do outro que não recaia apenas em opinião pessoal. Entretanto, se esta resposta subir bastante e o Gabe decidir botar em produção, podemos deixar a critério dele.

Comment: @VictorStafusa certo. Só para esclarecer aqui não é uma questão de pt_PT vs pt_BR.

Answer (score 3):

Estava lendo sobre Machado de Assis e vi que o editor dele, Louis Garnier, teve papel importante no mercado editorial brasileiro. Mas creio que não é um nome que se reconheça facilmente.

*Anyway*, a leitura me levou até a página [Categoria:Editores_do_Brasil](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categoria%3aEditores_do_Brasil), onde um nome salta à vista: [**Monteiro Lobato**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monteiro_Lobato), escritor, tradutor e *editor*.

Na correspondente [Editores de Portugal](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categoria%3aEditores_de_Portugal), não reconheço nenhum.

Comment: Esses editores são *publishers*, não *editors*. Tá difícil nomear essas medalhas!

Comment: Nem eu conheço nenhum :D

Answer (score 3):

Para não mexer na **Revisor** de bronze: [(ver esta pergunta)](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2440/medalha-revisor)

- Editor
- Mestre de edição
- Camões

Answer (score 3):

Minha sugestão para essa medalha:

### Léxico

Comment: Para quem assim que nem eu não fazia ideia do significado: http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/l%C3%A9xico
+1

Comment: Eu ia por, mas não deu tempo. Mas o interessante é que em Portugal tem um site assim com o dicionário deles: http://www.lexico.pt/. E essa palavra é PT-BR também. Obrigado por colocar.

Answer (score 2):

Ideia que me ocorreu agora, baseada no mercado editorial:

- Corretor/copidesque (bronze)
- Revisor (prata)
- Editor (ouro)

O problema de corretor é que lembra corretor imobiliário além de corretor ortográfico-gramatical — minha ideia é algo que se aproxime de *spellchecker*. Copidesque é uma alternativa, mas costuma ser confundido com revisor.

Além disso, minha sugestão reposiciona as medalhas Revisor e e Editor e eu não sei como o Stack Exchange encara esse tipo de mudança.

Comment: Corretor, Revisor e Editor cria uma hierarquia boa e não acho que cause polêmica.

Comment: O que quer dizer "copidesque"?

Comment: Eu leio "copidesque" como "copydesk". Acho isso horrível. Talvez chamar simplesmente de "corretor de textos"?

Comment: @bigown Acho que revisor encaixa melhor na outra medalha de bronze. Estas 3 não me soam nada bem...

Answer (score 2):

#### Corretor automático

Acho que seria uma boa: frequentemente nos deparamos com a *ajuda* do corretor automático.

=)

Answer (score 2):

Minha sugestão é alter a **Copidesque** para prata:

#### Alteração inicial

- Editor (Bronze)
- Copidesque (Prata)

#### Sugestão (Ouro)

- TOC - **T**ranstorno **O**bsessivo **C**ompulsivo
- Escriba - "O escriba era aquele que na antiguidade dominava a escrita e a usava para redigir as normas do povo". [(wiki)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escriba)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Minha sugestão:

- **Pasquale** para Prata
- **Evanildo Bechara** para Ouro (http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evanildo_Bechara)

Comment: Eu não vou dar +1 porque nem conheço este **Evanildo Bechara**.

Comment: Mesmo o Evanildo Bechara parecendo um cara mais ****, o  Pasquale ainda é mais conhecido. Porém temos que ver também se isso não gera problema com pessoal que fala português mas não é do Brasil

Comment: @PauloRoberto Ele escreveu várias gramáticas. O que ele fala pra língua portuguesa é quase lei. Participou também da última reforma ortográfica.

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz Mas o Pasquale não é imortal. O Bechara é. Fama é diferente de importância.

Comment: O Bechara é um grammar nazi no mau sentido! Já eu sou grammar nazi no bom sentido, hehe!

Comment: Se dermos a medalha de ouro para o Pasquale talvez ele passe a ser imortal :) Não faço idéia de quem é esse Bechara aí.

Comment: Se for para incluir o Pasquale, que é mais divulgador do que linguista, concordo com o Bechara ou mesmo gramáticos mais populares (e.g. Cunha & Cintra) para ouro.

Comment: *Muito prazer, Evanildo, eu sou Rodolfo...* - nos meus 40 anos de leitura, nunca tinha visto o nome; Bechara me soa familiar porém, deve ser o próprio... Artisticamente falando, o nome me parece horroroso em comparação com a elegância de Strunk & White.

Comment: Não me diz nada...

Answer (score -1):

Para a medalha de bronze temos no momento Editor. Chama-se "Editor" apenas porque já sabe clicar no botão de "Editar".

Para a medalha de ouro temos no momento Revisor. Revisor é a pessoa que executa o trabalho de revisar.

O que ficaria entre as duas?

### Melhorador

Comment: Essa palavra soa muito estranha para meus ouvidos, cheguei até a desconfiar que ela não existia no dicionário, mas existe. Mas mesmo existindo não gostei dela :/

Comment: @Math Aprimorador é mais legal kk

Answer (score -3):

Acho que opções descontraídas cai bem. Minha sugestão:

- Editor (bronze)
- **Professor Girafales** (prata)
- Revisor (ouro)

Comment: É-me estranha essa ordem. Um editor é, via de regra, mais experiente e com mais responsabilidades do que um revisor.

Comment: Isso é bem subjetivo, pra mim nada mais é do que um sinônimo.

Comment: Concordo com @Bavarious, no mercado editorial são funções diferentes, não tendo nada de subjetivo.

Comment: O que o @brasofilo comentou. Aliás, se editor fosse sinônimo de revisor, faria sentido um ser bronze e o outro ouro?

Comment: Essa ordem foi herdada da versão em inglês: editor/strunk & white/copy editor

Comment: @bfavaretto Ugh. Aliás, só percebi agora que na verdade Editor (bronze) e Revisor (ouro) já é a tradução usada aqui. =/