# Onde estão os tracejados sob os hyperlinks?

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto, design

O meta SOPT ainda não tem hyperlinks tracejados, que são utilizados pelo SO. As cores utilizadas no meta para textos e hyperlinks não permitem a fácil distinção entre os dois e, por isso, tracejados são necessários. Como exemplo, as experiências de tentar achar os hyperlinks [aqui](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late) e [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/473/quem-e-strunk-white-em-portugues) são completamente diferentes, embora a primeira pergunta seja bem maior.

Já me peguei "escaneando" perguntas com o mouse ou inclinando o monitor para poder achar os hyperlinks. Pessoas com maiores problemas de visão podem ter ainda mais dificuldades, então deveríamos pensar em importar os queridos tracejados.

Comment: Tenho tido o costume de por links em negrito sempre.