# Tradução nas medalhas

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Como se pode ver nesta pergunta: [Quem é Strunk & White em português?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/473/quem-%C3%A9-strunk-white-em-portugu%C3%AAs) ela não chegou a ser traduzida.

E ainda tem ali o *Awarded* por traduzir (talvez Adquirida ou Conquistada) e o **ganhadores** para mudar para "vencedores".

<kbd>[image: medalhas na central de ajuda]</kbd>

A frase do link poderia ser traduzida em "Outros usuários com esta medalha." E *Awarded* para "Concedida".

Comment: "ganhadores" soa estranho, mas "vencedores" sugere que alguém venceu uma competição - o que não é o caso aqui, pois todos podem ganhar a medalha desde que "cumpram uma meta". Na minha opinião, está bom do jeito que está. E "Awarded" eu traduziria para "Concedida".

Comment: "Outros usuários com esta medalha."? Concedida parece-me bem.

Comment: Esse bug de tradução não é exclusivo dessa medalha, ele está em todas as medalhas que só podem ser adquiridas uma única vez. Ex: Comentador, Tenaz, Entusiasta, etc. Acho que você deveria corrigir sua pergunta pois ficou bem confuso, eu já cliquei para visualizar ela procurando o botão de fechar, justamente por causa da pergunta que você linkou, mas logo depois eu percebi do que se tratava.

Comment: @Math está melhor assim?

Comment: Por mim, está sim.

Answer (score 2):

I've internationalized "Awarded" and "to". They will be deployed shortly, and they will also need to be localized before appearing correctly.