# Medalha Revisor

Tags: debate, status-pronto, medalhas

Estava dando uma olhada na lista de medalhas, quando me deparo com isso:

[image: duas medalhas revisor]

Temos duas medalhas distintas chamadas de "Revisor"!

O nome original da medalha de ouro é "Copy Editor".

O nome original da medalha de bronze é "Proofreader".

E por sinal, a medalha de ouro está relacionada ao já complicado [Strunk & White](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/473/132).

Qual das duas medalhas deveria ser renomeada? Se for a de ouro, é conveniente levar isso ao tópico do Strunk & White?

Comment: Victor qual o nome original das 3 primeiras?

Comment: @JorgeB. Editor, Strunk & White e Copy Editor.

Answer (score 2):

Para não mexer na **Revisor** de bronze:

- Editor
- Mestre de edição
- Camões

Comment: +1 embora eu não concordo muito com o Camões (mas não tenho nenhum bom motivo contra). Além disso, de quebra você encontrou um bom substituto para o Strunk & White.

Answer (score 0):

Estou apoiando mais [essa resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1289/101) para o trio de medalhas de edição. Então acho que a de bronze aí deveria ser mudada para outra coisa.

Ficaria com [**copidesque**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copidesque).

Pode não ser perfeito mas dá uma ideia geral do que é.

Comment: Particularmente não gosto de copidesque. Soa muito esquisito para mim.