# Faltam dados nas informações sobre os candidatos

Tags: bug, eleição

Estava a olhar para a página das eleições e o link *[Mais informações sobre os candidatos.](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#pt.stackoverflow)*

Nessa página aparece uma descrição dos candidatos em numeros e mostra também algumas medalhas importantes que foram ou não conquistadas.

Dei conta que muitos dos candidatos têm medalhas que essa página diz não terem...

Por exemplo *Eleitorado* e *Espirito Esportivo* (Electorate e Sportsmanship) eu e mais alguns candidatos têm mas lá aparecem a vermelho, como não conquistadas.

Bug?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Isso é um bug conhecido. [O Gabe comentou sobre isso no chat das eleições há uns dias atrás.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22159535#22159535) Basicamente, o problema é que o site busca as medalhas pelo nome, e como o nome em inglês é diferente do nome em português, ele não acha as medalhas, com exceção da Strunk & White, que ainda tem o nome em inglês [porque nunca se chegou a um consenso de como traduzí-la para o português.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/473/132)

Comment: O elections.stackexchange.com não é mantido por nós, mas sim por 2 usuários do SOen. Eu conversei com o autor da página sobre esse bug e a possibilidade de traduzi-la no futuro. Como é um trabalho voluntário, a solução dos problemas (e novas funcionalidades) aparecem quando os autores tem tempo.