# A medalha "tumbleweed" incentiva posts ruins?

Tags: debate, medalhas

Afinal, ela requer que o usuário crie um post sem nenhum comentário, resposta ou avaliação, não seria isso um prato cheio para os caçadores de medalhas?

Comment: Eu encararia isso como um desafio hehehe - uma postagem não repetida, a ver com o assunto citado, com um título não chamativo, passando totalmente despercebida.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De acordo com essa tópic no meta SE: [What is the purpose of the tumbleweed badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1576/229289), essa medalha serve como um prêmio de consolação.

Como você não recebeu praticamente nenhuma atenção na resposta o sistema te dá algo para você não ficar tão desapontado.

Isso pode atrair posts ruins? Talvez. Mas eu diria que não, e se isso por um acaso ocorre não chega a ser um problema, pois se você fizer uma pergunta ruim tentando caçar a medalha você estará sujeito a receber votos negativos ou votos para fechar, ou até mesmo um comentário perguntando o que você quis dizer com a sua pergunta. Logo o sistema não te dá a medalha por perguntas ruins, te dá a medalha por uma pergunta que não recebeu atenção nenhuma.

Essa medalha só pode ser adquirida uma única vez, então ninguém pode virar um especialista em fazer perguntas que passem despercebidas. Apenas faça perguntas, um dia eventualmente você ganha essa medalha.

Um caso real aconteceu comigo, eu recebi essa medalha no SO.com por uma pergunta que eu fiz que passou despercebida. Mas ela passou tão despercebida mas tão despercebida que depois de um ano ela foi apagado automaticamente pelo sistema, logo não chegou a criar ruídos para a comunidade.

A propósito, dê uma olhada nesse tópico: [Tradução para a medalha “Tumbleweed”](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/3117), pode ajudar a esclarecer um pouco mais.

Comment: Por que essa medalha não foi traduzida até hoje?

Comment: @Andrey adoraria saber. Fora isso também existem outras pendências que ainda não corrrigiram, como por exemplo a [medalha esportista](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/961/3117)

Comment: @Andrey Algumas traduções dependem da equipe de desenvolvimento fazer a internacionalização e então o Gabe usa uma ferramenta para conseguir fazer a tradução. Mas existem muitos detalhes a serem fechados, bugs a serem corrigidos e novos recursos a serem implementados com maior prioridade. Como a equipe internacional cuida dos mais de 100 sites da rede, então só conseguem atuar em alguns itens a cada semana. Mas não se preocupe, o Gabe e os moderadores estão acompanhando os pedidos e algum dia isso vai sair.

Comment: @utluiz Tranquilo! =) É que a impressão que dá é que certos posts no Meta ficaram esquecidos. Mas isso não é uma reclamação, é só uma constatação. =)

Comment: se eu fazer uma pergunta chamada `Podem me ajudar a ganhar a tumbleweeb?` você deixariam ela intocada? kkk

Comment: @RodrigoBorth acho que você conseguiria ganhar a medalha "Pressão dos colegas", serve? :P

Comment: @Math tambem serve kkkkk http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26326/me-ajudem-a-conseguir-a-medalha-thumbleweeb

Comment: @RodrigoBorth Num acredito que você fez isso!!

Comment: @Math sei que vai contra as regras e muitos podem não gostar, mas acho que não faz mal umas brincadeiras de vez em quando kkkk

Comment: Acabei ganhando... http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26379/elemento-arrast%C3%A1vel-se-sobrepondo

Answer (score 0):

Eu ganhei a Tumbleweed pela pergunta [Testar ViewModel KnockOut com CucumberJs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23179/testar-viewmodel-knockout-com-cucumberjs)

Eu não se se a pergunta ficou mal formulada, ou se não encontrei pessoas que trabalhem com o Knockout, mas o que ficou para mim foi a vontade de respondê-la, mesmo depois de ela ter tido uma recompensa sem nenhuma resposta (a não ser a minha)

PS.: Deve ter ficado confusa mesmo pois eu tb ganhei a TumbleWeed no SOEn por ela

Comment: A verdade é que *frameworks* Javascript existem aos montes, e você parece ter misturado três coisas nessa pergunta: **KnockoutJS** + **CucumberJS** + **TDD/BDD** (não conheço Cucumber). Quanto menos usadas as ferramentas e mais complexa a pergunta menor a chance de alguém responder.

Comment: @Andrey Exatamente, só queria demonstrar um caso onde o uso da medalha foi interessante. Pois realmente serviu como prêmio de consolação :D

Answer (score -3):

Eu ganhei e não gostei , não acho que alguém queira.