# Notificação quando se recebe uma nova medalha

Tags: suporte, medalhas, notificações

Observei que não se recebe alguma notificação quando se obtém um nova medalha, existe alguma razão para tal?

Comment: Notificação de que tipo? A parte superior da tela (onde aparece `+x` quando você ganha reputação) também mostra as medalhas.

Comment: Acho que é esse tipo de notificação mesmo, @mgibsonbr. Só que nem sempre aparece para medalhas de bronze. Ver minha resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quem tem a partir de 200 pontos de reputação é considerado veterano e deixa de receber notificações sobre a maioria das medalhas de bronze (as de prata e ouro sempre notificam), **exceto**:

- Boa resposta
- Boa pergunta
- Eleitor
- Escavador
- Capelo
- Pergunta popular
- Revisor
- Ressurgimento
- Criador de sinônimos
- Tumbleweed ([sem tradução aqui ainda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-a-medalha-tumbleweed))
- Vox Populi
- Anunciador
- Precognitivo
- Curioso
- qualquer medalha de tag (bronze)

**Fonte: [Which badges do not cause a notification for experienced users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138113)**