# O retorno de Tumbleweed e Strunk & White

Tags: debate, tradução, internacionalização, medalhas

Mais de um ano se passou e a discussão sobre estas duas medalhas esfriou:

[Tradução para a medalha "Tumbleweed"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-a-medalha-tumbleweed)

[Quem é Strunk & White em português?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/473/quem-%C3%A9-strunk-white-em-portugu%C3%AAs)

De lá para cá, muita coisa mudou na nossa comunidade e ela ficou muito mais madura e rica. Entretanto, estas duas medalhas continuam tendo os seus nomes em inglês.

Então, o que podemos fazer?

- Abrir uma nova discussão no meta para estas medalhas, e não deixar elas serem fechadas como duplicatas, e deixar as discussões antigas de lado.
- Requentar e dar nova vida às discussões antigas e tentar chegar a uma posição definitiva.
- Deixar isso de lado e continuarmos com o nome destas medalhas em inglês.

E então, como proceder com o debate destas medalhas?

EDITADO (06/02/2015): "Tumbleweed" agora se chama "Esqueceram de Mim", já foi para produção. :)

Comment: Parece que "Tumbleweed" vai virar "Esqueceram de mim". O "Strunk & White" está mais complicado.

Comment: Fiz uma nova sugestão para o "Strunk & White": http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2439/132

Comment: O tópico do Tumbleweed caiu no esquecimento... A ironia ataca novamente :P

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk - Muito boa @Math

Comment: Eu devo ser o único que gosta de "Strunk & White", por mais que esteja em inglês.

Comment: @rrnan Acho que sim. Considero este nome horroroso mesmo em inglês.

Answer (score 3):

Vou dar uma resposta um pouco mais geral já que entendo que o objetivo desta pergunta é tentar resolver definitivamente os nomes das medalhas.

Tem três visões claras que podem ser adotadas:

- Deixar tudo em inglês.

  Então teria que reverter o que foi feito. É uma solução simples. Alguns dirão que o nome não expressa com clareza o que é a medalha. A maioria dos nomes, mesmo em inglês não conseguem passar isto e não acho que era a intenção. Era mais para ser nomes bonitinhos. Nem a descrição delas, mesmo em inglês, dá para entender bem o que é a medalha.
- Podemos ficar tentando achar o exato significado de cada nome usado em inglês

  Provavelmente vamos ficar discutindo um tempão e não vamos chegar a lugar algum.
- Usarmos os nomes que quisermos apenas com a preocupação de passar um entendimento básico do que ela é, esquecendo seguir à risca o que estava escrito em inglês.

  Isto é bem mais prático e acho que devemos preferir esta forma. Assim fica mais fácil achar um nome. Não vejo porque devemos seguir fielmente o que está em inglês. Se é para localizar (nem sei se precisava) vamos fazer do nosso jeito. Não é só traduzir literalmente.

Então vamos escolher alguma coisa para efetivar. Já que existem perguntas para os temas já abordados, vamos deixar que a decisão saia de onde já está sendo analisado.

Particularmente não acho que vamos achar um nome que agrade todos e é melhor usar outra estrutura, acho que [essa resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1289/101) é a que chegou mais perto do que pode ser consenso. Pode não parecer porque algumas pessoas acham bonitinho usar Pasquale ou algo assim mas isto não vai dar consenso.

O que precisa é localizar logo o que falta e encerrar o assunto, 1 ano para tomar uma decisão boba dessas é muita coisa. Se um dia alguém encontrar um problema, muda-se.

Comment: +1 "Usarmos os nomes que quisermos apenas com a preocupação de passar um entendimento básico do que ela é, esquecendo seguir à risca o que estava escrito em inglês."